# when i want use eval() to open apex url i get blow error

Tags: javascript, json, apex

i use this code to open apex modal dialog page but when i use '' like this

```
var url='f?p=101:7:&SESSION.::::&P7_ID,&P7_ALLOWCHANGE,&P7_WFDEF_ID:8461,1,69004';  

   eval(url);
```

i get this error (

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

)
and when use ""

```
 var url="f?p=101:7:&SESSION.::::&P7_ID,&P7_ALLOWCHANGE,&P7_WFDEF_ID:8461,1,69004";  

   eval(url);
```

i get this error

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'
```

and this work fine when dont pass any parameters

please if anyone know anythings help me i need that

thanks

Comment: In js [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is used to evaluate a string containing JavaScript code - something that should not be done in general -, but your `url`  variable does not contain any JavaScript code. It is not really clear why you want/have to use `eval`.

Comment: @t.niese so what can i do ? url is apex url format

Comment: @t.niese i dont have much skill in js i see eval in website and use it

Comment: It seems you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

Well , when you use eval you put in literal string and eval execute it like code also you must have  " = " in literal code line.

If you action have no operation = than :

```
eval ("var ANYTHING = someFunction")
```

> In code snippet redirect can be done because link not exist !

```js
// if this is your new url 
var url="www.YOURWEBSITE.com";

url = url + "f?p=101:7:&SESSION.::::&P7_ID,&P7_ALLOWCHANGE,&P7_WFDEF_ID:8461,1,69004";  

setTimeout(  function () {

eval ("window.location = url")

} , 5000 )
```

```html
AFTER 5 SEC  YOU WILL BE REDIRECTED
```

Working snippet :

```js
function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
    return frameRef.contentWindow
        ? frameRef.contentWindow.document
        : frameRef.contentDocument
}

var YOURPAGE_window = document.getElementById("windows");
var url="https://maximumroulette.com/webgl2";  
setTimeout(  function () {
  YOURPAGE_window.src = url;
  //eval ("iframeRef(YOURPAGE_window).location.href = url")
} , 5000 )
```

```html
Worked (update)!
You will be redirected

<iframe id="windows" src="https://maximumroulette.com" ></iframe>
```